# Connecting to SQL server via MATLAB from Linux Ubuntu

Tags: java, sql-server, linux, matlab, jdbc

**I am trying to connect to SQL server via MATLAB from UNIX machine.**

*below are the steps that I followed:*

1. downloaded the SQL JDBC driver. below is the classpath I'm using in my javaclasspath.txt file
   `'/home/usr/JDBCdriver/sqljdbc_6.0/enu/jre7/sqljdbc41.jar'`
2. I have placed the javaclasspath.txt in the prefdir location. 
    `.matlab/R2016b/`
3. I have imported the Java libraries from matlab. below is my matlab code

   ```
   import java.sql.*;    
   import java.sql.DriverManager.*; 
   import java.lang.*;
   import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
   import java.sql.Driver;

   javaObjectEDT('com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver');
   ```

below is the Error:

```
Error using javaObjectEDT
No class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver can be located on the Java class path
```

Note: *I have done this through Windows Machine earlier, it worked like a charm but not sure how to do it through Linux. I'm a newbie to Linux world*

I'm not sure if I have specified the correct path?
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Have you tried these steps? You didn't list them all, so that's why I'm asking.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/microsoft-sql-server-jdbc-linux.html

Comment: I did try it using the database toolbox as well. its connecting using the server authentication but its throwing me an error when I use windows authentication. Here is the error `the driver is not configured for integrated authentication. Not sure yet how to tackle that issue.`

Comment: Getting the below error`java.sql.SQLException: `   
 `at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)`    
 `at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)`

Comment: Is your SQL Server set up for integrated authentication? Otherwise, you may need to try using SQL Authentication (username and password method).

Comment: Please provide all information in the question itself, do not use comments for that. Post the full code you use, and post the entire stacktrace. Also please learn how to properly format code on SO (don't use back ticks, but indent by four spaces, if in a list: 8 spaces, if after a list, first add non-list text). Also note that the currently posted code is useless for us to understand what you are doing and what is going wrong.

Comment: Thanks @andrea-lam. I was able to communicate with SQL server with SQL server authentication.

Comment: Thanks @MarkRotteveel for the tips. That was my entire code. It was failing in the initial stages.